# delete row from df if conditions are met

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to delete rows from my df that meet certain conditions in this case if two items have the same identification.

Previously I could use

```
for n, x in enumerate(names):
if "GDS" in x:
    df.drop(n, inplace = True)
```

This worked fine as it was one list but now I'm working with two different lists with different amounts of elements enumerate won't work (or at least I don't know how to make it work).

```
for z in tickDel:
for i in ticker:
    if z == i:
       (delete row in ticker with i string)
```

Ive tried loads of combinations such as df.drop(i, inplace = True) but i just get 
    KeyError: "['BRNB.L'] not found in axis"

My Dataframe looks like this

```
   Ticker TV Ticker YF                                              Names                 Sectors Industry
0        ABD     ABD.L      ABERDEEN NEW DAWN INVESTMENT TRUST PLC ORD 5P           Miscellaneous      yyy
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
df=df[df['Ticker TV'].ne(df['Ticker YF'])]
```

Comment: worked perfect thanks. What does the .ne do exactly?

Comment: It worked perfect in the test db I was using but when I applied it to the main db only changing the csv it reads in it doesnt work